# Using Jacobi Elliptic Functions for the solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the following ODE:
$$
Ay''-By^3+Cy=0
$$
where $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ (i.e.- positive constants).

After reading a little bit about the properties of the Jacobi sn function, I think the solution should contain sn in it, but have no idea how to arrive to it.

Will you please help me understand how to formally obtain the solution for this ode?

In addition, is there any book that contains solved examples for odes with Jacobi functions as solutions?

Thanks !

Comment: here you will find some informations http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality your equation is
$$y''+cy-by^{3}=0$$
Let $y(x)=\alpha{g(z)}$ and let $x=\beta{z}$ for constant $\alpha$, $\beta$. Than
$$g''+c\beta^{2}g-b\beta^{2}\alpha^{2}g^{3}=0$$
The Jacobi elliptic function $sn(z, k)$ satisfies the equation (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiEllipticFunctions.html)
$$f''+(1+k^{2})f-2k^{2}f^{3}=0$$
thus
$$k^{2}=\frac{b\beta^{2}\alpha^{2}}{2}$$
and
$$\frac{1+k^{2}}{c}=\beta^{2}$$
So, 
$$\beta=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+k^{2}}{c}}$$
To find alpha use the first equation 
$$\alpha^{2}=\frac{2k^{2}}{b\beta^{2}}=\frac{2ck^{2}}{b(1+k^{2})}$$
And so, 
$$\alpha=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2ck^{2}}{b(1+k^{2})}}$$
So, with any choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we've found, we will get the equation fo the $sn(z, k)$

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the degree of freedom. With $y(z) =f+g\sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda}\frac{1}{(z/e-\lambda)(z/e-\lambda-h)}-\frac{1}{\lambda(\lambda-h)}$  we need to look at its Laurent expansion $y(z) = \sum_{n=-1}^3 a_n z^{n}+\mathcal{O}(z^4)$ (where $a_n$ depend on $e,f,g,h,\Lambda$) and solve it at $z=0$ and $z=h$. The rest should follow from the fact entire elliptic functions are constant.

Comment: @reuns There is 1 degree of freedom constant-wise, obtained by the elimination of constants by an extraneous/implicit division and an explicit substitution ($y=\alpha g$).

Answer (score 2):

$$
Ay''-By^3+Cy=0
$$
This is an autonomous ODE. The method to solve it is :
$$
2A^2y''y'-2ABy^3y'+2ACyy'=0\quad\to\quad A^2(y')^2-\frac{AB}{2}y^4+ACy^2=c_1
$$
$$
Ay'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{AB}{2}y^4-ACy^2+c_1}
$$
$$
dx=A\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{AB}{2}y^4-ACy^2+c_1}}\quad\to\quad x=A\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{AB}{2}y^4-ACy^2+c_1}} 
$$
$$
 x=\sqrt{\frac{2A}{B}}\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{(y^2-y_1^2)(y^2-y_2^2)}}=
\sqrt{\frac{2A}{B}} \frac{1}{y_2}\:\text{F}\bigg(\sin^{-1}(\frac{y}{y_1})\:,\:\frac{y_1}{y_2} \bigg)
$$
where $y_1^2$ and $y_2^2$ are the roots of $\quad \frac{AB}{2}Y^2-ACY+c_1=0$

F$(\:\:,\:\:)$ is the elliptic integral of first kind.

with the related inverse function :
$$
y=y_1\:\text{sn}\left(\sqrt{\frac{B}{2A}} \:y_2\: x \:\:,\:\:\frac{y_1}{y_2} \right)
$$
sn$(\:\:,\:\:)$ is the Jacobi elliptic sn function.

Comment: Wow! Very nice ! Thanks a lot !